# Can't appendChild Inside a Tr>Div

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 tables, When I try to **appendChild** second table into the table1 (`tbl1`) tr, the table2 (`tbl2`) autumaticaly remove `<table...>` tag:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var tabletr = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    var rowtr = tabletr.insertRow(1);
    rowtr.appendChild(document.getElementById("tbl2"));

    rowtr.outerHTML = "<div>" + rowtr.outerHTML + "</div>";
 
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl1' style='background: lightblue;'>
<tr>
<td>table 1 - 1-1</td>
<td>table 1 - 1-2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>table 1 - 2-1</td>
<td>table 1 - 2-2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<hr />
<table id='tbl2' style='background: lightgray;'>
<tr>
<td>table 2 - 1-1</td>
<td>table 2 - 1-2</td>
</tr>
</table>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: `<div>`'s are not valid children of `<tbody>`, and `<table>`'s are not valid children of `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to put div in cell.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var tabletr = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    var rowtr = tabletr.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = rowtr.insertCell(0);
    cell.colSpan = 2;
    var div = document.createElement("div"); 
    div.appendChild(document.getElementById("tbl2"));
    cell.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl1' style='background: lightblue;'>
  <tr>
  <td>table 1 - 1-1</td>
  <td>table 1 - 1-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>table 1 - 2-1</td>
  <td>table 1 - 2-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<hr />
<table id='tbl2' style='background: lightgray;'>
  <tr>
  <td>table 2 - 1-1</td>
  <td>table 2 - 1-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `appendChild()` the second table, it's removed from it's current place in the DOM and inserted where you direct it. That's how it's [supposed to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).

You also end up with invalid HTML. The only valid children of `<tr>` elements are `<td>` (or `<th>`) and rows must have at least one of these children to themselves be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending the table, it gets moved. If you want to copy it, clone it. Also, don't edit the outerHTML. Corrected snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
  var tabletr = document.getElementById("tbl1");
  var rowtr = tabletr.insertRow(1);
  rowtr.appendChild(document.getElementById("tbl2").cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl1' style='background: lightblue;'>
  <tr>
    <td>table 1 - 1-1</td>
    <td>table 1 - 1-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>table 1 - 2-1</td>
    <td>table 1 - 2-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table id='tbl2' style='background: lightgray;'>
  <tr>
    <td>table 2 - 1-1</td>
    <td>table 2 - 1-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```